# Attributes/tags from com.google.ads namespace in styles.xml

Tags: android, admob

I am new to Ads and was able to successfully add my first ad in my android app using the code below in my layout.

mylayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="xxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Since I have multiple layouts in my app, I moved the common AdView attributes (e.g. adSize, adUnitId, etc,.) to styles.xml to reduce the code size. However, after this change, I am running into errors like 
`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ads:adUnitId'.`
`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ads:adSize'.`
`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ads:loadAdOnCreate'.`

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" >

    <style name="MyAdView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="ads:adSize">BANNER</item>
        <item name="ads:adUnitId">xxx</item>
        <item name="ads:loadAdOnCreate">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I don't have problems with the **android**:xxx tags, the problem seems to be only with **ads**:xxx. Is there anything else that I should be doing to use com.google.ads namespace.
Since everything works fine when I have the code in the layout, I think I have everything I needed to add ads in my app (AdMob SDK, admob lib in build path and order & export, etc,.).
Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the style resource only for style related attributes, if you want to *factorize* the id you should use a string resource like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="admob_id">XXX</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @gipi. I see similar errors for all the attributes from ads: namespace, including adSize, which I think is a style attribute. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think that since the `jar` of the library doesn't contain `XML` files with the resources you can't refer to them: you don't have the ads.R namespace available.

Comment: Just to be clear, ads:xxx work fine in layout xml. I see the errors only when I use them in styles.xml.

Comment: I know, I tried the code myself; the `com.google.ads.AdView` is contained in the `jar` and since is not a proper Android library, then you can't access or refer to its namespace in the styles.xml. I would like to be contradicted

Comment: Thanks again @gipi. I accept this answer and continue using layout files for ads until I find a better way to handle this.